# How to wrap paragraphs or text inside of a tag in Notepad ++

Tags: html, tags, notepad++, html-editor

I'm using Notepad ++ and I'm trying to wrap sentences or paragraphs inside of

tags. Is there a way to automatically do this or a way to select the text that you want and then add

tags? Better yet, is there another HTML editor that will do this? I'm a novice here and still learning. Thank you.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61647021/edit) and add sample text and expected result.